# How to rename all files in a folder using gulp js?

Tags: node.js, gulp

I have a bunch of `html` files in a `partials` directory. Using gulp js, I want to minify and rename these files to `.min.html`. Please show me how to achieve this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

See [here](https://github.com/hparra/gulp-rename#usage), using gulp-rename, if you just want to rename the files.

Something in the line of below should do:

```
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
gulp.src("./partials/**/*.hmtl")
.pipe(rename(function (path) {
  path.suffix += ".min";
}))
.pipe(gulp.dest("./dist"));
```

In order to minify, you can use [gulp-htmlmin](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/gulp-htmlmin). Pretty straightforward from the documentation:

```
var htmlmin = require('gulp-htmlmin');

gulp.task('compress', function() {
  gulp.src('./partials/**/*.html')
    .pipe(htmlmin())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
});
```

You can certainly combine the two to obtain the desired effect.

Comment: Thanks @Mangled.. I've updated your answer (added few corrections).. Cheers!

Comment: Your edits were rejected as far as I can tell. Not a big deal anyhow - as long as you got the idea and made it work! Best! ;)

Comment: Too bad! :( Well, I just changed the `path.suffix` to `path.basename` and added some final code. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm using this to compile handlebars templates to html, so in my case I just use `path.extname = ".html"`

Comment: may they changed, but for me the suffix needed to be `path.extname`